# Strict concavity in the closure of a convex set

Tags: convex-analysis

Is the following statement true?

Let $f:X\to \mathbb R$, $X$ normed vector space, be a continuous function that  is strictly concave function over a convex set $C$, then $f$ is strictly concave over $\bar C$ (the closure of $C$).

Comment: How about something like $x^2+xy^2$ and $C = (0,1) \times (0,1)$?

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä That function is not concave nor convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: try the counterexample $f(x,y)=\sqrt[3]{xy}$ on $x>0$, $y>0$.

Comment: You are right. Your counterexample works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that statement is correct. Consider the function $$f(x)= \begin{cases} &-x^2 & ,x>0 \\ &1 &,x=0 \end{cases}$$
and let the set $C =\{ x\,|\, x>0\} $. Then $f$ is strictly concave over $C$, but it is not concave over $Cl (C)$.

Comment: But this function is  not continuous.

Comment: I see my statement was ambiguous. I have edited it.